# log error on tomcat displayes on apache

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I have `tomcat7` and `apache 2.4` connected with `mod_jk`.

I see on webmaster tools, that every day i have pack of errors, but unfortunatelly i don't see them.
Catalina.out and all apache logs are without errors.

Once i've opened my site and i've seen `503` but i was only once and i didn't save this error.

How to configure apache, to save on log file tomcat errors?

A add, that in jk.conf is `JkLogLevel info`.

Thanks

Comment: What is "a pack of errors"? What specific errors are you seeing? Do you have a tomcat.log? A 503 error from the http server can mean that the tomcat instance is not running.

Comment: ok, i see on localhost.log only this: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException